# microsoftgraph events that are all Day show UTC, not the correct time zone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I request events "https://graph/microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events", the ones that are all day are flagged as such, but show the wrong times.

Right now they show midnight to midnight but in UTC.  My calendar is in CST (CDT now).  I don't have a problem with it coming back in UTC, but I would expect 5am to 5am UTC now that we are in DST.

Is there someplace else I should be looking for the Timezone other that in the Start and End fields?

Answer (score -3):

"All Day" events are scoped to a given date not a time and are therefore not adjusted for time zones. When you create an all day event in Outlook you are saying it occupies that date (i.e. January 1st = New Years Day) regardless of which time zone you happen to be located in.

Comment: Maybe, but then since Graph explicitly shows UTC for the Time Zone, how are you supposed to tell what time zone it is really for?  The Web Service API shows full day event correctly.

Comment: You could retrieve the mailbox's timezone using [mailboxSettings](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings).

Comment: That is probably a possibility.  But, I would have to add an addition scope just to get their mailbox to find their time zone.  If I have to, that is the route I will take, but this sure seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Looks like the mailboxSettings returns the timezone in a string format, but does not indicate DST. So for instance, If I get back "Eastern Standard Time", I have no way of knowing whether it is Indiana or New York.  New York observes, Indiana does not.  So even though I know when DST starts and stops, I have no way of getting exact times.

Comment: What solution did you end up going with for this problem? I am running into the same situation. I don't know how I should display the all-day event to users in other timezones, such as to say that the original user is busy from 12:00 AM to 12:00 AM in their local time only. Or is that too specific?

Comment: It would be better if the all-day events would be as date, not an aware-datetime with UTC timezone

Comment: Hard to believe that someone from Microsoft really answered like "ignore timezone".  Absolutely ignoring the fact it will means DIFFERENT time span for anyone from other zones....